# Tab container in the Tabbar is not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create the Tabbar with 3 tabs but the result is not as expected. Since I try to give the size of container of Tabs but it doesnot reflect in the output.
Also, In the results white underline below the tabs.
Any help will be appreciated, Thank you!!!

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.grey[100],
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: DefaultTabController(
                length: 3,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Material(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 18.0, right: 18),
                        child: Container(
                          height: 45,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
                              border: Border.all(
                                color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 225, 220, 220),
                              ),
                              color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 225, 222, 222)),
                          child: TabBar(
                            physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                            indicator: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            tabs: [
                              Container(
                                height: 42,
                                child: Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  child: Text(
                                    "11月分",
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                height: 42,
                                child: Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  child: Text(
                                    "12月分",
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                height: 42,
                                child: Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  child: Text(
                                    "1月分",
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: TabBarView(
                        children: [
                          Center(child: Text("chat")),
                          Center(child: Text("messages")),
                          Center(child: Text("request")),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Current result:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: Couldn't reproduce. what emulator are you using?

Comment: @MendelG I am using Android emulator of Android Studio.

Comment: Ok, although I can't reproduce it on a physical Android device.. I guess wait for other answers.

Comment: Add dividerColor: Colors.transparent to your TabBar()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of each individual tab is limited by the size of the entire `TabBar` minus the padding that is given to it. You can decrease the size of the padding to give more space to the tab items:

```dart
TabBar(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5), // change 10 to 5
  // ...
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**This code is to remove the white line in the tab bar**

```
dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
```